# Dystopian trilogy: dying Earth, wealthy people living in orbital stations, main character goes on the ground and is trapped there because of a war

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I would like to reread a fantastic novel (actually a trilogy).

The Earth is dying consumed by war and eco problems. Some people live wealthy in orbital stations. That's where the main character lives, but she decides to go to the planet for some time to study at university. But the war breaks out, and she can't return to space (Book I).

The dystopia is here, and she spends years trying to return home, including fighting with cannibals and other "adventures" (Book II).

Once at home, the colonies star a trip to a far away planet. When they arrive, the woman is an old woman who can hardly stand up. But in the end, she fulfils their dreams after all (Book III).

Comment: More details would be good. Do you remember how she fulfilled their dreams, perchance? We also have a list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. Answering them, and editing those answers into your question, will help everyone involved.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/302478.The_Exiles_Trilogy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely to be Joe Haldeman's "[Worlds](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?441)" trilogy.

The three volumes split up as you describe:

- Vol 1 [*Worlds*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92414.Worlds), the protagonist leaves the orbital habitat New New York to visit Earth.
- Vol 2 [*Worlds Apart*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21629.Worlds_Apart), dealing with the aftermath of an apocalyptic war. Her significant other is trapped somewhere on the Earth
- Vol 3 [*Worlds Enough and Time*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21613.Worlds_Enough_and_Time), a starship journey to a new star

As much as I loved early Haldeman works, this is about where he started to lose me, so I don't remember the details too well. But there are enough matches to make me think this is it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!  *The Forever War* it's one of my favourite science fiction novels, but I like these too.  I can't wait to read them again!.

Comment: You're most welcome, and welcome to sf stack exchange!